# Trouble converting mySQL function to PDO while retaining variable names - Almost have it

Tags: php, mysql

I had the following PHP mySQL code:

```
$q = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE admin_id = '" . $admin_id . "'");
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $user_settings[$arr['setting']] = html_entity_decode($arr['value']);
}
```

In my database I have a table with settings. Each row has an admin ID, a setting name, and a setting value.

For example, a row could be:

```
id|adminid|setting|value <-column names
1|1|settingName1|5
```

The code above resulted in variables in this format:

> $user_settings['settingName1']

which had the value of "**5"** from the database.

I'm trying to convert this to the PDO methods that are used by WHMCS. This is my first time working with PDO. I'm trying to get the variable names and values to match the old way so that less code changes are required

So far I came up with this:

```
    foreach (Capsule::table('tablename')->where('admin_id', '=', $admin_id)->get() as $user_settings) {
echo "<pre>".print_r($user_settings, true)."</pre>";
    }
```

That outputs:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 16
    [admin_id] => 1
    [setting] => settingName1
    [value] => 5
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 15
    [admin_id] => 1
    [setting] => anotherSetting
    [value] => ON
)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 14
    [admin_id] => 1
    [setting] => yetAnotherSetting
    [value] => ON
)
```

I have no idea how to get these settings to match the old format.

For example, the three examples shown above should end up like this:

```
$user_settings['settingName1'] (value should be: 5)
$user_settings['anotherSetting'] (value should be: ON)
$user_settings['yetAnotherSetting'] (value should be: ON)
```

I would really appreciate some help as I learn how PDO works.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out for hours now. I have it close, it's reading the data from the database, I just can't figure out how to get it into the format I need.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), you want to have it as an array instead of an object

Comment: Use the `->` syntax to read object properties: `$user_settings->setting`.

Comment: there is no PDO in this question

Comment: @YourCommonSense aparently this "Capsule" this uses PDO. I'm not quite sure, that's what the documentation says.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this really is my first time using something other than mySQL to read from a database. Can you explain in a little more detail what you mean?

Comment: **`get()`** is not a PDO function. None of it looks like PDO. It might be using PDO under the covers, but the code looks like it's using Laravel (or some other ORM that follows a pattern similar to Laravel.)  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#introduction

Comment: @spencer7593: That's got nothing to do with MySQL or PDO.  You just have an object, so you need to read it using `$user_settings->setting` instead of `$user_settings['setting']`.

Comment: So I'm not even looking for the right thing. Would explain why I'm not having much luck.

The documentation did mention Laravel, and something about PDO. I don't know what either of them are.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. $user_settings['audioAlert'] had a value, but doing $user_settings->audioAlert does not.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a question about Laravel Query Builder, not a question about using PDO.

If the goal is populate an array from the query return, using the value in the "setting" column as the array key, and assigning the value from the "value" column, then something like this:

```
$user_setting = Capsule::table('tablename')
                ->select('setting','value')
                ->where('admin_id',$admin_id)
                ->pluck('value','setting');
```

---

**EDIT**

The example above does not include a call to `html_entity_decode` function, which the original did.

One option would be to process the array after its populated... loop through the array, run each array value through the `html_entity_decode` function, and take the return and assign it back to the array. PHP has some clever array manipulation syntax for doing that (building a new array out of another one.)

Otherwise, if we want to loop through the objects returned from the query, and assign each row to an array, then we could do something like this:

```
   $user_setting = []; // PHP 5.4 or later, < 5.4 use "array()" instead
   foreach(     Capsule::table('tablename')
                ->select('setting','value')
                ->where('admin_id',$admin_id)
          as $obj) {
     $user_setting["$obj->setting"] = html_entity_decode("$obj->value");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of *PDO*, this brilliant library indeed [has a fetch mode designed exactly for your case](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_KEY_PAIR):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT setting, value FROM tablename WHERE admin_id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$admin_id]);
$user_settings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

While that home-brewed query builder you are using most likely makes this mode unavailable.

Comment: I'm using the WHMCS billing system. The documentation is here: http://docs.whmcs.com/Interacting_With_The_Database I just don't understand any of this stuff. Normal mySQL was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive my goal by doing it like this:

```
foreach (Capsule::table('tablename')->where('admin_id', '=', $admin_id)->get() as $user_setting) {
    $array = get_object_vars($user_setting);
    $user_settings[$array['setting']] = $array['value'];
}
```